# Warum gibt es kein e im Plural weniger "Für weniger kritische Gemüter stellte es jedoch eine große Beruhigung dar."?

Tags: declension

Warum nicht:

> Für **wenigere** kritische Gemüter stellte es jedoch eine große Beruhigung
>   dar.

[Urschrift](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=w8KYDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=F%C3%BCr%20wenigere%20kritische%20Gem%C3%BCter%20stellte%20es%20jedoch%20eine%20gro%C3%9Fe%20Beruhigung%20dar.&source=bl&ots=5M7Ql6WULE&sig=ACfU3U1kyPppNkb8Z8rC7XFjhZyjWSVeHQ&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjavr6cxp_jAhWnllQKHQtmCeIQ6AEwCHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=F%C3%BCr%20wenigere%20kritische%20Gem%C3%BCter%20stellte%20es%20jedoch%20eine%20gro%C3%9Fe%20Beruhigung%20dar.&f=false):

> Für den nachfragenden Geist war das ewige Universum aber schon damals
>   eine Provokation. Für **weniger** kritische Gemüter stellte es jedoch eine
>   große Beruhigung dar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not Plural. *Gemüter* is Plural, but *wenige* qualifies *kritisch*. You can be less or more critical. In this case, less. Hence it's *weniger*.

Would be the same, if the object they are referring to was Singular, e. g. "Für ein weniger kritisches Gemüt..."

Plural would be *wenige*. But then it would qualify *Gemüter*. "Für wenige kritische Gemüter..." would mean there are **few** and **critical** minds, not **less critical** minds. It would probably be understood to mean that it was reassuring to few critical minds, i. e. not reassuring to many or even most critical minds.

*Wenigere* is [comparative](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wenigere) and doesn't fit in here.

Comment: Ah, I had the same problem a few weeks ago, but I kept reading it as fewer critical minds. Now it seems obvious that it is less critial. wie weniger kritisch von mir